# jQuery clone based on div contents

Tags: jquery, clone, contains

I am trying to clone a div's contents only if its content matches a third divs content, so far I have got the clone part to work but can't figure out how to check the contents against another div.

```
$(function(){
var $button = $('.duration').clone();
$('#ewp-div').html($button);
});
```

I want to clone the contents of ".duration" to "#ewp-div" , but only if the ".duration" contains the same text as a h1 tag?

I have a fiddle with what I have so far..

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/aqp0adnx/

Comment: Matches or starts with? It seems none of the elements match the text in the H1, but some of them start with the same string etc.

Comment: @adeneo: `"contains the same text as a h1 tag"` was specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `:contains` selector, or use a `filter`. Either will reduce the matches based on the supplied values/rules.

A basic `:contains` selector looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aqp0adnx/1/

```
$(function(){
    var $button = $('.duration:contains("September")').clone();
    $('#ewp-div').html($button);
});
```

You can obviously drive the `contains` value (September) from the contents of your H1 like this using string concatenation to build the selector:

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/aqp0adnx/2/

```
$(function(){
    var $button = $('.duration:contains("' + $('h1').text() + '")').clone();
    $('#ewp-div').html($button);
});
```

**Update based on comment:**

If you want to match the whole H1 (like "September 14") then it will already work *as-is*:

http://jsfiddle.net/aqp0adnx/3/

If you only want to match the first word for instance, separate that out first based on the space character:

http://jsfiddle.net/aqp0adnx/4/

```
$(function(){
    var $button = $('.duration:contains("' + $('h1').text().split(' ')[0] + '")').clone();
  $('#ewp-div').html($button);
});
```

*The rules/logic of how you want to match it is up to you. For example an exact match would need to apply a `filter`, but that would not seem to be appropriate for your example data*

If you want exact matching, or complex rules use `filter` with a function. The function is called for each element in turn. If the function returns true the element is kept (else it is discarded).

e.g. This does an exact match instead: http://jsfiddle.net/aqp0adnx/6/

```
$(function () {
    var h1 = $('h1').text();
    var $button = $('.duration').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == h1;
    }).clone();
    $('#ewp-div').html($button);
});
```

Comment: how do I fix this if the h1 contains more than the "September"?

Comment: Q: If the h1 contains say "September 2014" would you want to match  anything with "September 2014" (which it will do now) or just "September"?

Comment: Just september, the actual format it comes in is "Event for September 2014" I just need to make sure "September" is in there

Comment: @user1625357: Answer updated to include pretty much every option you could want. If you need anything more complex, please provide a sample of the new data :)